# No output in command prompt

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

My program, which is for generating an acceptable password, is not displaying any output aside from input prompt and it lets me input the password but the program immediately ends. I get no errors on my end or warnings on my debugger. Was wondering if someone could give me some input.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char password[15] = {'\0'};
    char search[15] = { '\0' };
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    char punct[] = { '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?','_', '\0' };

    printf("Enter your test password: \n");
    fgets(password, 15, stdin );

    a = strnlen(password, 15);//judges length of search between the numbers 2 and 15
    b = strncmp(password, punct, 10);
    c = isalpha(strnlen(password,15));
    d = isdigit(strnlen(password, 15));
    e = a + b + c + d;

    if (a < 2 || a>15) {

        printf("Must have exactly 2-15 characters.\n");

        if (strncmp(password, punct, 10) == false) {//must have one of the characters included in password
            printf("Must have character punctutation\n");
        }
        if (isdigit(strnlen(password, 15)) == false) {
            printf("Must consist of at least one number 0-9.\n");
        }
        if (isalpha(strnlen(password, 15)) == false) {
            printf("Must consist of at least one letter a-z\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("You have inputted a legal password!\n");
        }

    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: your input length is >= 2 or <= 15?

Comment: why are you doing isalpha on a length? and isdigit? (unrelated)

Comment: I thought if it ran array with isalpha or digit that it would give me a int that i in turn could use for a true false statement

Comment: isalpha and isdigit test a character, not a string, search for each to get their proper usage

Comment: `char password[15]` --> `char password[15+2]` as `fgets()` needs room for the `'\n'` and `'\0'`.  Use `fgets(password, sizeof passowrd, stdin );` and strip trailing `'\n'` off after `fgets()`.

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to have punct array  scan through passwords to have it return an integer or a true statement if possibleif one of the symbols is detected in passwords array

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an output because `strnlen(password, 15)` is between `2` and `15`,  use an `else` part:

```
if (a < 2 || a > 15) {
   ...
} else {
   /* your output here */
}
```

On the other hand:

`if (isdigit(strnlen(password, 15)) == false) {`

is a nonsense, `isdigit` checks if a character is a decimal digit, but you are passing a `size_t` instead of a `char`, same for `isalpha`.

Comment: Is there a command or loop that will let do something that will let me scan the inputted char. I just thought the isdigit would return a 0 (false) which could translate into comparing it with a true false statement

Comment: did not help and I am possibly more confused now than before